# Why CORS settings is not needed when we upload to S3 via `aws-sdk` gem

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, cors, jquery-file-upload, aws-sdk

I have a rails app which have feature to uploads files on S3. For this purpose, I am using `aws-sdk` gem. The files are being uploaded to S3 but files first gets uploaded to server and then the files are being transferred to S3.

To make it quick, I switched to `Jquery-file-upload` plugin which allows me to upload files directly to S3 without server's intervention. However, to support this I needed to add CORS configurations to my S3 bucket.

So question is, why CORS configuration was not needed earlier when I was uploading the file via `aws-sdk` gem?

Answer (score 1):

CORS is used to get around the same origin policy which restricts which hosts you are allowed to connect to from your client side script. It only applies in the browser. There are no such restrictions on your server side app or the server-to-server connection you use to forward files from your server.